# How to handle user session in Service Provider if the user is deleted in GSuite SSO SAML

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace

I’m trying to implement G Suite sso in my React + Node.js application. So far, i’ve got the authentication part working. Now, when a user is deleted from G Suite, how do i delete it from my service provider (Node.js custom application). I haven’t found any user deletion callbacks for this from G Suite.

Thanks